# Usage onclick in a text/javascript code

Tags: javascript, onclick

Presently i am using the following code for Add view and Delete button group in side text/javascript.

```
jsonData.data[i][5] = '<div class="btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons"><a href="more_log.php?more=' + jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add</a><a href="delete_well.php?delete='+ jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete </a><a href="well_veiw.php?view=' + jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a></div>';
```

Now i want to add a confirm onclick against delete as

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete  this well and its associated logs...?')"
```

I tried this way, but not working

```
jsonData.data[i][5] = '<div class="btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons"><a href="more_log.php?more=' + jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add</a><a href="delete_well.php?delete='+ jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete  this well and its associated logs...?')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete </a><a href="well_veiw.php?view=' + jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\` before `'` as you are adding string in string.

```
jsonData.data[i][5] = '<div class="btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons"><a href="more_log.php?more=' + jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Add</a><a href="delete_well.php?delete='+ jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete  this well and its associated logs...?\')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete </a><a href="well_veiw.php?view=' + jsonData.data[i][0] +'"_blank" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a></div>';
```